# GKE Autopilot: How to set custom DNS

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

I have GKE Autopilot with version version 1.27 and my organization had internal DNS. How do I connect my internal DNS to GKE k8s dns, I am unable to hit make any changes on kube-dns configmap as kube-system namespace is restricted, any help.

GKE cluster uses cloud dns but unsure how to connect it with internal dns.

GKE Autopilot uses cloud dns, I have connected GCP VPC network but nothing happens. Pods are unable to get the dns resolution from our internal DNS. Tried to update kube-dns configmap but its restricted. Please assist

Error from kubedns configmap:

error when patching "dns-cm.yaml": configmaps "kube-dns" is forbidden: User cannot patch resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system": GKE Warden authz [denied by managed-namespaces-limitation]: the namespace "kube-system" is managed and the request's verb "patch" is denied